# Showing progress dialog while loading database in Android

Tags: android

I am loading a database without problems in a `SQLiteOpenHelper>>onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)` method.

However, when I try to wrap the loading of the database in an `AsyncTask` in order to show a progress bar, I keep receiving the message that the database is closed(!). What is the reason of that ?

As an example, this code works fine :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
    ...
    String sqlStatement = ... //content of file with sql
    for (String sqlStatement : sqlCode.split(";")) {
        db.execSQL(sqlStatement);
    }
}
```

But if I wrap the same code in a class (indirectly) extending `AsyncTask`, I will receive the error message saying that the database is closed :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
    new LoadDBTask(context, db, progressDialog, alertDialog).execute(new Integer[] {scriptId});
}
```

`LoadDBTask` extends `ProgressAsyncTask`, that at it turns extends from `AsyncTask`. It wraps the same code than above. It also takes care of showing the progress bar.

Here the code for `LoadDBTask` :

```
public class LoadDBTask extends ProgressAsyncTask<Integer> {

    protected Context context;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;

    public LoadDBTask(Context context, SQLiteDatabase db, ProgressDialog progressDialog, AlertDialog alertDialog) {
        super(progressDialog, alertDialog);
        this.context = context;
        this.db = db;
    }

    public boolean loadScript(String sqlCode) {
        for (String sqlStatement : sqlCode.split(";")) {
            sqlStatement = sqlStatement.trim();
            if(!sqlStatement.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    db.execSQL(sqlStatement);
                } catch (Exception e) {  
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Problem executing SQL statement: "+sqlStatement,e);
                    return false;
                }
            }   
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            int scriptId = params[0];
            String sqlCode;
            try {
                sqlCode = ResourceUtil.getFileContent(context.getResources(), scriptId);
                return loadScript(sqlCode);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error reading script file: ",e);
                return false;  
            } 
    }
}
```

And for completeness, here the code of `ProgressAsyncTask` :

```
public abstract class ProgressAsyncTask<Params> extends AsyncTask<Params, Integer, Boolean> {

protected ProgressDialog progressDialog;
protected AlertDialog alertDialog;

public ProgressAsyncTask(ProgressDialog progressDialog, AlertDialog alertDialog) {
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    this.alertDialog = alertDialog;
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... changed) {
    if(progressDialog != null)
        progressDialog.setProgress(changed[0]);

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    if(progressDialog != null)
        progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if(progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    if(!result) {
        if(alertDialog != null)
            alertDialog.show();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown us where you're *closing* the `db` so I'm going to assume you're closing it soon after:

```
new LoadDBTask(context, db, progressDialog, alertDialog).execute
  (new Integer[] {scriptId});
```

I.e. in your *calling* class and this is most likely where your error lies. Move the DB closing statement to the `onPostExecute` method and that should solve your issue.

Of course, you will have to override `onPostExecute` in `LoadDBTask` to do this. Remember that `AsyncTask` is **asynchronous** and as such it will *not* block at the `new LoadDBTask` statement I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Handler handler;

public yourConstructor(Context context){
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("wait");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    handler = new Handler();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
    progressDialog.show();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //your bd access here

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                }
            );
        }
    }).start();
}
```