# how to make a splash screen wait for a database to load

Tags: java, android, xml, database, manifest

i am new to android programming and u may find this silly but here is my question:

In my app I have a SplashScreen, a login form and a main form. On launching
the app, I'd like to show the SplashScreen while reading config files and
attempting a database connection. I show progress of these tasks on a label
on the SplashScreen form.
Once this is completed ok, the splash screen should close and the login form
should be displayed. A successful login closes that form and shows the main
form.

so i am stuck on how to make my splash screen dependent on getting the database and how to make the login form appear after my splash screen and not the main activity.

if there is anyone kindly can help me with the code of the java and the manifest class ill be gratefull :)

Comment: You're likely to get better response if you post code you've tried, so that people can help you with that. The question you've posted is just asking people to do the work for you.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953876/showing-progress-dialog-while-loading-database-in-android

Comment: i did do any coding cuz i didnt know the way to do it , i just wanted to ask about the methods needed to do this then continue my search :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AsyncTask to load data in background using it's doInBackgroundString...params) and onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) to publish the progress into your view , and onPostExecute(Long result) method to end the splash screen .

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: thanks for the answer , that's what i wanted :) cheeers